# Adding an external link to a menu (beginner)

Tags: link, menu

I have inherited our website which is built on Craft CMS. I need help figuring out how to add a link to an external URL from a menu on our site: https://sofheyman.org/

I cannot figure it out. Can anyone offer me some advice as to where to start

Comment: There are a virtually unlimited number of different ways your developer could have set this up, if at all. Craft has no prescribed way of handling this kind of thing, or any other. We'd need a lot more detail to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi James! Let me know what details I can add or screenshots I could take to help get help

Comment: @JamesSmith Let me know what details I can add or screenshots I could take to help get help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out how the navigation is created in the template. It could be completely hard-coded in the template, in this case you would have to manually edit the template to add your additional menu items. However, usually the navigation is based on a data source, it's only a matter of finding where the data is coming from.

To find out where the data is coming from, you need to find the template that's been used to display the homepage. In a development environment where admin changes are allowed, go to **Settings** -> **Sections**. There's usually a section of type *Single* there that's used for the homepage. Check the settings to see what template is being used for the homepage. Then open that template in a code editor, and try to find the part that's responsible for rendering the navigation. This might be in a different template that the main template is including. To find that template, check all templates that the main template is including with the `include()` function or extending with the `{% extends %}` tag.

In the template that's displaying the navigation, see what data it is loading for that purpose. For example:

1. Is it using `craft.entries()`? Then it's just displaying entries, usually from a structure, and you can probably add a new item by creating a new entry.
2. Is it accessing a [global set](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/globals.html)? Then you can add a menu item through that global set.
3. Is it accessing `craft.navigation` somewhere? Then it's probably using the [*Navigation* plugin](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/navigation/docs/template-guides/navigation-field) and you should have a section in the Control Panel called *Navigation* where you can add new menu items.

There are a lot more options, but the template is always the starting point to find out how something works. If you're unsure how to do any of this, you will need a developer to do this type of change for you. In general, it's much easier to ask the developer who built the site how something works than try to reverse-engineer the functionality.